# Unable to refresh updated appointments in Service Calendar

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm unable to refresh the Service Calendar view when I'm updating fields on an appointment record.

In this first screenshot I've created a new appointment and my Users are attached to the following fields:

- Organizer: Pu Bjerre
- Required: Konrad Viltersten and Annie Kruse

The created appointment gives the following view in the Service Calendar.

[image]

Now I want to update my appointment by following changes.

1. Rescheduled the appointment time by one hour
2. Removed Annie Kruse from the *Required* field

After I've updated my appointment and refreshed the Service Calendar, this is the view the service calender shows:

[image]

It seems that my service calender is only viewing the updates I'm adding, not the updates I'm removing. The only way I'm able to remove Annie Kruse is by closing the browser and log in again into the organization.

No idea what that depends on. Also, I'm not sure how to handle it. Is it by design? Or is it a know (mis)behavior? The usual googling led to nowhere.

Comment: For imaginery +1. (Yoda English due to warning when commenting.)